# Accessing pytest options set in pytest.ini in marking conditions

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pytest

I'm writing tests for webapp and sometimes it takes a while for changes to be visible at the production server. I didn't want these tests to fail but I didn't want to ignore them either.  Thus I want to mark such tests as xfail when running against production server but I am failing to access the options object in the marking which can be accessed inside of the testcase. As soon as these tests would pass with XPASS, the marking would be removed. Also those tests should not be

Is there any possibility to do that?

```
@pytest.mark.xfail(
    options.getini("base_url") == options.getini("production_server"), 
    reason="Change not yet deployed to the production server")
def test_apidoc(self, request, base_url):
```

The only workaround I can see is this:

```
def test_apidoc(self, request, base_url):
    not_production_ready(request)
    if request.config.getoption("base_url") == request.config.getini("production_server"):
        pytest.xfail("Changes not yet deployed to the production")
    pass
```

but that will ignore the test immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attach markers dynamically - I would introduce another marker, e.g. `provisional_xfail` that serves only one purpose: if the settings match the desired ones and the marker is present, the test gets an `xfail` marker added. Example:

```
# conftest.py

def pytest_collection_modifyitems(config, items):
    if config.getoption('prod') == True:
        for item in items:
            if item.get_closest_marker('provisional_xfail') is not None:
                item.add_marker(pytest.mark.xfail(reason='Should fail for now with prod settings'))
```

The test gets the `provisional_xfail` marker:

```
import pytest


@pytest.mark.provisional_xfail
def test_spam():
    assert False
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I had to edit your add_marker function a little because it didn't accept the `reason` parameter. 
So, instead I've used `item.add_marker(pytest.mark.xfail(reason='Should fail for now with prod settings'))`
Apart from that, it worked like a charm!

Comment: @lukashino shame on me! You're right, `add_marker` doesn't accept marker name with args. Updated the answer.